# Firebase realtime database: how to get the value of a parent node

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Let's say I have database nodes structured like below: Each user sets username of his/her preference, and his/her UID assigned by Firebase auth is logged under the username.

```
"uid_match":
 {
   "username_1" : {
      "uid" : "firebase_uid_1"
    },
   "username_2" : {
      "uid" : "firebase_uid_1"
  }
```

I'm trying to write codes to extract the username by the firebase uid. It will look for a certain firebase uid and return the username, which has its own URL.

Below is the part of the code I wrote, but it returns '/uid_match', instead of '/username_1' or '/username_2'.

```
 let ref=firebase.database.ref('/uid_match');
 let user=firebase.auth().currentUser;
 ref.orderByChild('uid').equalTo(user.uid).once('value', function(snapshot) {
     window.location.href='/'+snapshot.key;
 })
```

Question: What will be the correct query code to extract "username_1" or "username_2", instead of "uid_match"? Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to iterate inside the `snapshot`, to retrieve the keys `username_1` and `_username_2`:

```
 let ref=firebase.database.ref('/uid_match');
 let user=firebase.auth().currentUser;
 ref.orderByChild('uid').equalTo(user.uid).once('value', function(snapshot) {
     snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot){
     window.location.href='/'+childSnapshot.key;
   });
 });
```